# Do if else condition in python need brackets?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
class oldest:
    #to find the largest age among three 
    def enter(self):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.c=c
        a=int(input("enter age 1"))
        b=int(input("enter age 2"))
        c=int(input("enter age 3"))
        
    if (a>b and a>c):
        max=a
    elif (b>a and b>c):
        max=b 
    else:
        max=c 
        
age =oldest()
print("The largest age among three are {self.max}")
```

The code is not executing. There is something wrong with the condition.

Comment: Can you please provide more examples or details to help clarify your question? As it currently stands, it's difficult to understand exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There's no `self.max` anywhere. And `self` can only be used inside a class method.

Comment: The `if` statements need to be in a method, and they should use `self.a`, `self.b`, and `self.c`.

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on OOP in Python, you don't seem to understand it, and SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Did you notice the NameError exception when you tried to run this?

Answer (score 0):

```
class oldest:
    def enter(self):
        a=int(input("enter age 1: "))
        b=int(input("enter age 2: "))
        c=int(input("enter age 3: "))
        self.max = max(a, b, c)
        
age =oldest()
age.enter()
print("The largest age among three is", age.max)
```

You can try above code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful ! Could you please help me what was wrong with my code?

Comment: if you need to apply the indentation in if else condition. second things that you did not call the class method.